# How to store MSSQL PRINT output to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On a MS SQL 2008 R2, I want to be able to catch the messages output into a variable. I need to run a script on many databases. Catch the message output (messages from print or raiserror) and log it into table. I need to do this from inside of a stored procedure.

For this script

```
Declare @sqlscript nvarchar(500)

Set @sqlscript = 
'select * from sys.objects
raiserror (''My raised error'', 10,1)
select * from sys.schemas
print ''my print'''

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlscript
```

I would like to get

```
My raised error    
my print
```

or

```
(60 row(s) affected)  
My raised error

(21 row(s) affected)  
my print
```

**Update**
I've decided to go with @rs suggestion. Logging into a table is the easiest way for me. Using a SP to log (to keep the code clean), plus a small regex to refactor all my scripts. The solution will be ready for tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: check `@@error`, `@@rowcount` after your exec statement Ex: `SELECT @@rowcount`

Comment: After the sp_executesql, both the @@error and @@rowcount are at 0, because the last statement is a print. It will only give me info on the last statement and not the entire script executed.

Comment: Can you use insert into table instead of printing? Replace `print 'my print'` with `insert into logtable (msg) values ('print')`

Comment: Yes, I could replace prints with a logtable or with a nvarchar(max) variable that I would append. But I have about 75 scripts that I would love not to have to refactor. :D Plus using Print is kindda standard for trace. I can change my habbits, it team that will be more reluctant to change.

Comment: @rs: You should make an answer with your comment so he could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the CLR and a technique similar to this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/09/13/capture-print-messages-from-a-stored-procedure.aspx

But the best option is to probably EXEC into a temporary table which simply has a single varchar column:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: CLR is just not an option, we're hosted on a server that doesn't provide us with the correct credentials to use CLR and the EXEC option  I've just tested it but I can't make it work. I can get results out of the Stored Proc, but not the messages.