# Get the output of a PRINT sql in string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

A small question

I am trying to run a db query through c#.
I am trying to print something on DB which I want to return as a string from C#

```
string altertable1 = "print 'scfs'";
SqlCommand altertable = new SqlCommand(createtablecommand, connection);

string x = altertable.(function which return the printed query result);
```

SO what i want is that **x** value will be **scfs**;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541991/how-to-store-mssql-print-output-to-a-variable

Comment: If it *has* to specifically be `PRINT`, I'm not sure that there's a way.

Comment: Could you use SELECT rather then PRINT?

Comment: It is not specifically select actually i have declared a variable which gets data, which i need in c#

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to capture the output of `PRINT` command, since it doesn't return any row readable through a `SqlDataReader` object.

I would consider a solution that stores the output messages of a query into a temporary table (for example `#outputMessages`) with just one `varchar` column. When the execution of your query is completed, I would capture its output messages stored into `#outputMessages` table with just a `SELECT * FROM #outputMessages`.
When the output messages capturing process is completed, just drop the temporary table.

Please also read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541991/how-to-store-mssql-print-output-to-a-variable) linked by @Corak.

Answer (score 0):

So I did it in a different manner ,
I declared a variable , and get my print statement data in that variable and rather than printing the variable , i select that variable in the last part.

Now for C# , i use `altertable.ExecuteScalar` which return the first row as string, so for me it was what I needed.

string altertable1 = "print 'scfs'";
SqlCommand altertable = new SqlCommand(createtablecommand, connection);

string x = altertable.(function which return the printed query result);